# reading bytes from a file to short / long integer

Tags: c++, integer, byte

Hiho everyone! I'm trying to read first 4 bytes of a file and store them in integer variable.
here's what I'm doing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream is;
    is.open ("binary_file.dat", ios::binary );
    char file_version[4];
    is.read(file_version, 4);
    int fv_int;
    memcpy(&fv_int, file_version, sizeof(fv_int));
    cout << fv_int;
}
```

But the result is not what I meant it to be. Program copies first byte of the file in correct position, but considers the rest of bytes to be 0's. Example:

First 4 bytes of my file:

```
10101010 00101100 00101100 00101100
```

What is the content of fv_int after program execution:

```
10101010 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Is there any way to access specific bytes of integer? Or maybe better method of reading bytes from a file?

Comment: Can't you just `is.read(&fv_int, 4);`? Also, why are you assuming that `int` is 4 bytes long?

Comment: You should use `int32_t` (from stdint.h) rather than int, as the size of int varies depending on the platform.  This probably doesn't solve your problem, but it will make your code more portable.

Comment: @H2CO3: C++ std::istream::read() takes a pointer to char.  Sad but true.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Damn C++'s strict type system.

Comment: You're welcome.  The second portability hint is that byte order matters.  On a little endian platform, the int will read differently than on a big endian one.  You need to use a function to possibly transform the integer if the program is to be portable--if you're on Linux see `man 3 endian`.

Answer (score 2):

istream::read does not read exactly 4 bytes, it returns number of bytes read. Check return value, your file may be too short

Additional hint:
You could do `is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&fv_int), size_of(fv_int));` to reduce amount of code and add verbosity

Comment: My file is 200 kBytes, so It's definitely not too short ;P
The functions return *this. <- c++ refference :(

Comment: oh, sorry `readsome` returns number =)
than check stream errors.
add something like 
`if(!is) cout << "error"`

Answer (score 1):

If I feed your program with files which have the first 4 bytes, it reads & displays them perfect. For further diagnosis, change the last cout to: `cout <<sizeof(int)<<" "<<hex<<fv_int<<endl;`

Comment: Strange, I'm checking in hex editor, and I'm sure it does not work correctly.

Comment: `hexdump -C binary_file.dat` gives me: `00000000  f0 f1 f2 f3 ...`, and your program (with the changed cout) gives me: `4 f3f2f1f0`, which is correct because I'm using intel processor

Comment: Ah it looks like I misunderstood hex editor. You are right, code works , what a relief. Thanks everyone